# Send Bytearray from PHP to Flex using AMFPHP?

Tags: apache-flex, codeigniter, amfphp

Anyone can give me an example of send an object of type bytearray from PHP to Flex using AMFPHP ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you did and how it failed, so we can help you fix it? We aren't here to do your work for you, you know...

Answer (score 2):

//Sending as Flash Native ByteArray Format using ZendAmf Php

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($file_path, NULL, NULL, $startbyte, $endbyte);
$bytearr_obj = new Zend_Amf_Value_ByteArray($buffer); 
return $bytearr_obj;
```